# Nelmio/api-doc-bundle error: non-existent service "api_platform.openapi.normalizer" (Symfony 4)

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, nelmioapidocbundle

I've a composer.json with these packages:

```
        "php": ">=7.4",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "api-platform/core": "^2.7",
        "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "1.0.19",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/collections": "~1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/event-manager": "~1.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/persistence": "~1.0",
        "exercise/htmlpurifier-bundle": "~3.0",
        "fig/link-util": "^1.0",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "4.11.1",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.3",
        "php-imap/php-imap": "3.0.6",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "predis/predis": "^1.0",
        "psr/cache": "~1.0",
        "psr/container": "^1.0",
        "psr/link": "^1.0",
        "psr/log": "~1.0",
        "psr/simple-cache": "^1.0",
        "seld/jsonlint": "^1.9",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~6.0",
        "snc/redis-bundle": "^2.0",
        "symfony/asset": "~4.0",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/cache": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~4.0",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~4.0",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.4|^5.0|^6.0",
        "symfony/expression-language": "~4.0",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.18",
        "symfony/form": "~4.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "~4.0",
        "symfony/http-client": "^5.2",
        "symfony/lock": "~4.0",
        "symfony/mailer": "~4.0",
        "symfony/mime": "^4.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~3.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "~1.8",
        "symfony/polyfill-intl-icu": "~1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "~1.5",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "^1.24",
        "symfony/property-access": "~4.0",
        "symfony/property-info": "~4.0",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "~4.0",
        "symfony/serializer": "^4.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.5",
        "symfony/templating": "~4.0",
        "symfony/translation": "~4.0",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "~4.0",
        "symfony/ux-chartjs": "^2.6",
        "symfony/validator": "~4.0",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.8",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.2",
        "twig/twig": "^2.9"
    },
```

So with "api-platform/core": "^2.7" and "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "4.11.1". Api platform is already working, but I've added nelmio/api-doc-bundle now.

When I clear the production cache however, php gives the following error:

```
php -d memory_limit=800M bin/console cache:clear --env=prod

 // Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false                                                        


In CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 86:
                                                                                                                                      
  The service "nelmio_api_doc.describers.api_platform" has a dependency on a non-existent service "api_platform.openapi.normalizer".
```

According to php bin/console debug:container, api_platform.openapi.normalizer indeed does not exist, and nelmio_api_doc.describers.api_platform it points to this class:

```
  nelmio_api_doc.describers.api_platform Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Describer\ApiPlatformDescriber
```

When I open this vendor class in projectdir/vendor/nelmio/api-doc-bundle/Describer/ApiPlatformDescriber.php, all use statements do exist.

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the NelmioApiDocBundle package.
 *
 * (c) Nelmio
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Describer;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Swagger\Serializer\DocumentationNormalizer;
use ApiPlatform\Documentation\DocumentationInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

final class ApiPlatformDescriber extends ExternalDocDescriber
{
    public function __construct(DocumentationInterface $documentation, NormalizerInterface $normalizer)
    {
        if (!$normalizer->supportsNormalization($documentation, 'json')) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Argument 2 passed to %s() must implement %s and support normalization of %s. The normalizer provided is an instance of %s.', __METHOD__, NormalizerInterface::class, Documentation::class, get_class($normalizer)));
        }

        parent::__construct(function () use ($documentation, $normalizer) {
            $documentation = (array) $normalizer->normalize(
                $documentation,
                null,
                class_exists(DocumentationNormalizer::class) ? [DocumentationNormalizer::SPEC_VERSION => 3] : []
            );

            // TODO: remove this
            // Temporary fix: zircote/swagger-php does no longer support 3.0.x with x > 0
            unset($documentation['openapi']);
            unset($documentation['basePath']);
            unset($documentation['servers']);

            return $documentation;
        });
    }
}
```

So why do I get the error message about the missing service? I can find nothing anywhre about this, except for decorating the service (https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1729), which is not the case here.

It did mention at https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1729 that api_platform.openapi.normalizer is an alias for api_platform.openapi.normalizer.api_gateway, so I added this to services.yaml:

```
api_platform:openapi:normalizer: '@api_platform.openapi.normalizer.api_gateway'
```

And now it appears as an alias in php bin/console debug:container, but still the exact same error message when I clear the cache.

```
 In CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 86:
                                                                                                                                  
 The service "nelmio_api_doc.describers.api_platform" has a dependency on a non-existent service "api_platform.openapi.normalizer".
```

Any ideas?